# Endless scroll kotlin recycling view/ListView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, infinite-scroll

I am desperately trying to implement endless scrolling on an android app using kotlin. All the tutorials are either useless since they dont explain things properly. So for example:
https://github.com/chetdeva/recyclerview-bindings

it looks promising but the author uses phrases like 
"put this in your BindingAdapter" so i look what this `BindingAdapter` is, I found a java file but if you insert anything in there I get errors. Its like anything I try fails directly.

The other tutorials are written in java and even with "translate to kotlin" option its useless since the translated code throws 100 errors.

I tried things like :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    list.hasFixedSize()
    list.adapter = ListAdapter(this, getLists())
    val list_view: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list)
    fun setRecyclerViewScrollListener() {
        list_view.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                val height = list_view.getHeight()

                val diff = height-dy
                if (diff < 1000){
                    /*load next list */
                }
            }
        })
    }
    setRecyclerViewScrollListener()
}
```

or this

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity)
val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.append_list, null, false)
button.setOnClickListener{screen.addView(layout)}
```

Is there a bullet proof method where you can simply append elemets like with html and js? I wrote this snippet in 2 min. Is there a similar "easy" way in Android/Kotlin?

```js
$("#next").click(function(){
  $(".append_text").append("new text <img src='http://static.webshopapp.com/shops/015426/files/005031634/560x625x2/kek-amsterdam-wandtattoo-hase-forest-friends-braun.jpg'/>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="next">Load</button>

<span class="append_text"> </span>
```

In general I recive a lot of errors for choosing the wrong Layout. I tried Listview and contrainlayout and recycling Layout and Vertical Scrolling layout and so on. Is there a simple body tag where you can simply append a xml file?

I think I go the wrong way the whole time because I see everything though the eyes of a Web. Dev. while android does not have the classical DOM. Can anybody explain it to me with an minimal example on how to append a xml file to the main xml file on button click/on scroll?

Answer (score 16):

I use this method for adding endless scroll functionality to a recyclerview in Kotlin:

```
private fun setRecyclerViewScrollListener() {
    scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            val totalItemCount = recyclerView!!.layoutManager.itemCount
            if (totalItemCount == lastVisibleItemPosition + 1) {
                Log.d("MyTAG", "Load new list")
                recycler.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
            }
        }
    }
    recycler.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
}
```

the variable lastVisibleItemPosition is declared as follows:

`private val lastVisibleItemPosition: Int
        get() = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()`

```
private lateinit var scrollListener: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
```

Just call the `setRecyclerViewScrollListener()` method every time you nedd to add this functionality to the recyclerView.

Hope it helps,

Leonardo

Comment: where do you define these methods? If I add this into my MainAct. into the onCreate function, `get`, `linearLayoutManager`, `LOG_TAG`, `chatRecycler`, `recycler` and `scrollListener` are either undefined  or cant be resolved. Where are the xml files?

Comment: @hansTheFranz I edited my code, sorry for the misprint, chatRecycler and recyler are the same RecyclerView, LOG_TAG is a string for logging purpose, I also added the declaration of scrollListener. linearLayoutManager is the layoutmanager you have to set to the recyclerview and get() is the getter for lastVisibleItemPosition variable.

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code, @LeonardoMedori. 
Can I ask you why you have this next line in your code?
`recycler.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener)`

Comment: @Rod I remove the scrollListener and I add it again after I finished updating the list. If I don't remove the listener the onScrollStateChanged method is called many times and (totalItemCount == lastVisibleItemPosition + 1) condition can be true more than once. So instead of having a boolean for checking if the list is updated I remove the listener, make a call, update the list and than add the listener again.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm i don't now if this solve your problem but i use this to implement an recycler view that added new data to my recycler view when the scroll come to the end:

```
productsListActivityBinding.recyclerViewProducts.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)){
                //function that add new elements to my recycler view
            }
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

set in recycler view in scroll listener

```
 recycler.addOnScrollListener(your listener)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.